# react-redux not updating state when the API returns an empty array []

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm using react-redux, my component updates correctly when the API server returns an array with one or more objects. Example:

```
[{"name":"John","id":245},{"name":"PEEEPEE","id":45},{"name":"Jeff","id":5},{"name":"Brett","id":22}]
```

When my API server returns:

```
[]
```

react-redux does nothing....

I'm using the redux chrome extension which is showing ACTION TYPE happening but the state is not updating... Any ideas why?

```
my store:

let store;

const initStore = ({onRehydrationComplete}) => {

  store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      ...reactDeviseReducers,
      form: formReducer,
      router: routerReducer,
      apollo: apolloClient.reducer(),
      cats
    }),
    {},
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(
        thunk,
        routerMiddleware(history),
        apolloClient.middleware()
      ),
      autoRehydrate(),
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    )
  );

  persistStore(store, {
    blacklist: [
      'form'
    ]
  }, onRehydrationComplete);

  return store;
};
```

My reducer:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = []

export default function catReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_CATS_SUCCESS:
     return Object.assign([], state, action.cats)
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me get this clear... the state is not being updated to an empty array when the server responds with an empty array? And the action is being dispatched?

Comment: That is correct....

Comment: Ok I'm sure this issue is with this line in the `catReducer` function - `Object.assign([], state, action.cats)` will not overwrite the previous state if `action.cats` is an empty array.

Comment: Interesting,,, what's the right way to handle this scenario?

Comment: The most straightforward approach is to return `action.cats`. Based on your implementation you're just returning the new result every time so there's no need to merge objects.

Comment: nice. that did it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with this line in the `catReducer` function:

```
Object.assign([], state, action.cats)
```

It will not overwrite the previous state if `action.cats` is an empty array. Based on your implementation you're just returning the new result every time so there's no need to merge objects with `Object.assign`. Instead just do `return action.cats`